# Is there a particular reason why Immanuel Kant didn't ever leave Königsberg?

Tags: kant

Was it just a coincidence because he simply never got the opportunity to, or because he refused to leave his home city for ideological reasons ?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, he never expressed any interest in leaving. He may have had little motive to leave since he had a good job and it was a good city in Prussia. But unless you can probe his mind,  there's not much else you're going to get on this question.

Comment: This is how the old-timers produced so much good, original  writing.  They didn't fool around with the internet, or wash their car, or travel around in circles. No playing around. Kant refused a horse and walked to town because he didn't want to bother with feeding a horse oats and apples.

Comment: @Gordon, travel broadens the mind. I find Kant's harping on absolutism particularly tedious and narrow-field, symptomatic of someone who was firm on his beliefs without truly experiencing perspectives other than his own.

Comment: @PKHunter You can as well broaden your mind by welcoming travellers, but staying at home. Just saying' (and sorry if this gets out of topic).

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't really answer your question in the terms given; but it might throw some light on it.

Arendt wrote in her short book, *The political theory of Kant*:

> How serious Kant was about the enlargenment of his own mentality is indicated by the fact that he introduced and taught a course on physical geography at the university.

then she goes on to say:

> he was an eager reader of all kinds of travel reports; and he - *who never left konigsberg* - knew his way around both London and Italy; he said he had no time to travel precisely because he wanted to know so much about every single country.

Answer (score 0):

I believe he did leave Koningsberg twice, both times for tutoring in the period after he had graduate from university but before he got a position in it. But I don't believe he ever left apart from for those two occasions for the reason of tutoring.

Comment: It would be helpful to post a citation to support the claim that Kant did leave Könisberg.

Comment: @philosodad. I would cite Hannah Arendt’s book quoted by Mozibur Ullah, above.

Answer (score 0):

King Louis XVI of France never left his Palace at Versailles during his life (except to be guillotined in Paris in 1793). People just did not put much value in travel at those times. The idea that brainlessly moving around has any usefulness is fairly recent.

Comment: Not everyone travels with 'brainless moving around'. It broadens perspectives in ways one cannot fathom.

Comment: “ People just did not put much value in travel at those times.”  I agree.  Martin Luther made it to Rome once, did not like it, and was pretty much a homebody the remainder of his life.